# Mongodb Collection and Schema

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongoose

I was looking to have my collection to be like this

```
movies : {
     spiderman : ["good" , " bad" , " excellent"] ,
     marvels   : ["good" , "ok" ],
     ironman   : ["good" , "bad"]
}
```

I tried with my schema like

```
movies : {
    spiderman : [String],
    marvels   : [String],
    ironman   : [String]
}
```

but i was not successfull. sorry if i did any error new to Mongo and Stackoverflow

Comment: The type is array, not string

Comment: can you tell me how to implemet that collection i'm new to mongo.if you have link to documentation please provide me.

Comment: oh i got schema should look like this right.                                    movies : {
    spiderman : [],
    marvels   : [],
    ironman   : []
}

Comment: Could you provide the complete code for the schema declaration?

Comment: Your original schema is correct. Can you update your question with the code you're using to create a document and also what's not working about it?

Comment: The field 'movies' must be an array but is of type String in document {_id: ObjectId('5654260662760dfe14339baa')}